# CMake: Include vs add_subdirectory: Relative header file path

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a c++ project with several subdirectories, e.g.

```
src/
  CMakeLists.txt
  main.cpp
  module1/
     CMakeLists.txt
     code.cpp
     code.h
  module2/
     CMakeLists.txt
     code2.cpp
```

It seems that the two ways to deal with this in cmake is to either use `add_subdirectory(module1)` or `include(module1)` in my `src/CMakeLists.txt`. Somewhere I read, that the `include` use is regarded legacy/deprecated. My `src/module1/CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})

set( SRCS
    ${SRCS}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/code.cpp
   )

set( QT_FILE_HEADERS 
    ${QT_FILE_HEADERS} code.h
   )
```

If I try to use the `add_subdirectory` method and want to use`code.h` in `main.cpp` I have to write `#include "module1/code.h"`. If I do the `include` method of adding module1,  I can simply write `#include "code.h"`. I would prefer not to specify the relative path of the include files when I use them somewhere else, is there a way to achieve this using the `add_subdirectory` method? I thought the `include_directories` line should have taken care of that.

Comment: CMake's `include` is definitely not deprecated or legacy

Comment: Often it is considered good practice to place header files into subdirectories to avoid name clashes and have a better structured `/usr/include` after an installation. It also removes the requirement to specify `-Imodule1` for users of your code.

Comment: If I remember it correctly, it was meant that using include to add subdirectories which contain their own CMakeList files

Comment: I don't see why this is marked as duplicate. The other post has nothing to do with the `include` keyword. In short, `add_subdirectory` introduces a new scope, whereas `include` does not. You'll find some more explanation in this post: crascit.com/2016/01/31/enhanced-source-file-handling-with-target_sources. I think in general it's better to use `add_subdirectory`, unless you need to use `include` for some reason. This can happen sometimes when defining a new target or enabling a new language in a subdirectory, for example.

Comment: @numberCruncher Does your code compile at all with `add_subdirectory`? In your `set(SRC...` statement there is no `PARENT_SCOPE` so it seems like that source file is not actually included.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not how you should make modules -- sure you can do it this way, it works,  but it is not very useful. Given your layout, simply reference `module1/code.cpp` in the main `CMakeLists.txt` file.

However, if you want to use modules, make each one a separate static library. This will really simplify things!

In `src/CMakeLists.txt` write:

```
add_subdirectory(module1)

add_executable(myprogram main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myprogram module1)
```

In `src/module1/CMakeLists.txt` write:

```
add_library(module1 STATIC code.cpp)
target_include_directories(module1 PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

This way, you are only passing one single thing back from the `module1` CMake script: the `module1` target. Your `main` doesn't need to know anything about what happens inside there. If the code in `module1` requires specific external libraries, link them there, the main CMake script won't need to know about it. Simply by linking to `module1`, all the magic will happen behind the scenes, your program will be compiled with the right include directories and linked to the right libraries.